# List the cron jobs scheduled by apscheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, apscheduler

I am using the [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module in my scripts to schedule a job for every last day of the month. I am running this python script as a `systemd` script in CentOS machine.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.add_job(lambda: my_aggregation_function(url_list, 'monthly'), 'cron', day='last')
    while True:
        sched.start()
```

I restarted my script(systemd) by adding these changes and the script is now running with the job scheduled.

My question is how do I confirm if the job is scheduled from my python script to be run as I configured. I did a cron list as below but couldn't find any listings scheduled.

```
crontab -u root -l
```

Also for a test job on interactive shell,

```
# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
>>> sched = BlockingScheduler()
>>> def job_function():
...     print "Hello World"
... 
>>> sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day='last')
<Job (id=c4b232a453dd4b5dbea5ef413d7a8c4d name=job_function)>
>>> sched.start()
```

How do I see the details of the job id (`c4b232a453dd4b5dbea5ef413d7a8c4d`) mentioned? Is it possible to look in this way.

Also I looked up another module [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) for managing `cron` jobs. This also didn't list the jobs

```
>>> from crontab import CronTab
>>> my_cron = CronTab(user='root')
>>> for job in my_cron:
...     print job
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a grave misunderstanding here. It seems you think APScheduler is somehow managing the system's cron jobs. It is not. It's an in-process scheduler which just happens to have a cron-like trigger for scheduling the jobs. APScheduler has no connection whatsoever to any cron daemon or crontabs.

Updating the actual answer from the comments. The API is defined in the [`apscheduler`](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.get_jobs) official documentation

```
scheduler.get_jobs()
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer (being the author of the module I suppose). I did confirm your opinion of the module not having to do anything with the actual `cron` daemon which linux provides. But taking only the `apscheduler` perspective, isn't is possible to list the scheduled jobs?

Comment: Sure it is, using [scheduler.get_jobs()](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.get_jobs)

Comment: Ah! Such a simple one! Not sure how did I miss that in the documentation.